# spring MVC <context:component-scan base-package="com.ginfo" />

Tags: spring-mvc

I am developing spring MVC using 3.0 annotation.  Controller class is presented in com.ginfo package and here is the code.

### HelloServletController.java

```java
package com.ginfo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloServletController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  
        String message = "HELLO SPRING MVC HOW R U";  
        return new ModelAndView("hellopage", "message", message);  
    }  
}
```

And this is the content of my `applicationContext.xml`.

### applicationContext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ginfo" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am getting error in the line `<context:component-scan base-package="com.ginfo" />`.

As a result `HelloServletController` is not executing.

And one more thing: I observed that when I created `applicationContext.xml`, I am not getting `xsi:schemaLocation` for `/context` and `/spring-context-3.0.xsd` like below:

```xml
<xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```

Instead I am getting like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I did this in my eclipse for `spring 8.6` and I added `spring 3.0 Core libraries`, `spring 3.0 web libraries`.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something in your `applicationContext.xml`, take a look at this (it's just an example i've just found in my workspace)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

...

</beans>
```

Of course, you need to have spring-context-3 in your classpath